# Left element of div is empty string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the left-position of my absolute positioned div. The style is pre-declared in css using the following:

```
#menu {
   position:absolute;
   width:200px;
   min-height:40%;
   left:-200px;
}
```

Now, when I try to check what the value of `left` is using javascript, it shows to be `""`. The following JS is used to check the value:

```
var menuElement = document.getElementById('menu');
console.log(menuElement.style.left);
```

I have set up [this codepen](http://codepen.io/mlangendijk92/pen/YPVRyw) as a demonstration. Note that this happens for both negative as positive left-values.

Why is the value of left always `""`?

For that matter, it appears that any style element is shown as `""`. Why is that happening?

Comment: Is jquery okay for you ?

Comment: I would rather not use JQuery, no.

Comment: I am not good with javascript but maybe this might help you http://jsfiddle.net/mmtdv9ew/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `getComputedStyle()` to get the rules declared via stylesheet.

```js
var menuElement = document.getElementById('menu');
var menuElement2 = document.getElementById('menu2');

console.log(getComputedStyle(menuElement).left);
console.log(getComputedStyle(menuElement2).left);

console.log(getComputedStyle(menuElement));
console.log(getComputedStyle(menuElement));
```

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 40%;
  left: -200px;
  background-color: black;
}
#menu2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 40%;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="menu2"></div>
```